# XCode 7 Autolayout Constraints: How to make 2 images stay horizontally in the center

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, constraints

I'm trying to position 2 UIImage views in the center of the screen, side by side. If it's just 1 UIImage, I can just set them to be vertically and horizontally center in the container. If I have 2 UIImage views side by side, I can only set it to be vertically centered, but not horizontally centered since both UIImage views would stack over each other..

Could someone please guide me ? Thanks and greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a view, put both the images inside that view. Add the constraints on those images with respect to the view you made (Edge to edge to the view). Now add the constraints on the view in respect of the super view. (Center vertically and horizontally). That's it!

Comment: Thanks, yes this would work. However, im looking for something a bit different. Lets say I have this 1 UIImage and I want to put it on the screen 33% of the screen in x coordinate ( y-coordinate doesnt matter) , how would I do that?

Comment: A bit tricky. I would have taken an outlet of that x constraint and modified it from the code.

Comment: Gandalf's answer also works but i think this answer is easier to understand from storyboard

Answer (score 2):

An elegant way to solve this is to apply constraints on `UIImageView` itself.

Now think that if you need to have both the image views in `superview's` centre then one `imageView` should have it's `trailing` edge at the centre of `superview` and another should have a `leading` edge at the centre.

`Control-Click` on `imgvLeft` and drag it to `superview`, you will see some constraint option to select; choose `trailing` edge constraint. Now go to that constraint and click it you will see details as shown in picture below. Change the `second item` from `trailing` to `centreX` and keep the constant 0.
Same way you can apply the `leading` constraint on `imgvRight` and change the `second item` to `centreX`.

Now if you wish to keep some distance between both the views then you can change the constant value in constraints. For example if you need an spacing of `20 px` then change the constant to spacing/2 i.e. 10.

[image]