# horizontally aligning two adjacent objects in Xcode Auto Layout

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am trying to horizontally center these two PickerViews in Xcode Storyboard:

[image]

Can anyone tell me the simplest way of doing this?

I tried putting both PickerViews in a container (UIView) and then centering the container horizontally but that created further complications.

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you mean vertically center as per your picture, you constrain one to the vertical center of the superview and then constrain the vertical centers of the two pickerviews

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: Yes, am using autolayout

Comment: When I say 'horizontally center' I mean placing the two picker views side by side so that each picker view is an equal distance from the center line. What I wanted to do is find a control (if it exists) that would combine the two picker views as if they were one object and then use the 'horizontal align center' command to place it equidistant from the left and right edges of the superview.

Comment: Check my answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544940/xcode-7-autolayout-constraints-how-to-make-2-images-stay-horizontally-in-the-ce/33545857#33545857](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544940/xcode-7-autolayout-constraints-how-to-make-2-images-stay-horizontally-in-the-ce/33545857#33545857)

Comment: @Gandalf I tried your method and it didn't work for me: the right hand picker view ended up right off the screen. I went through the procedure twice just to make sure.

Comment: Share the screen shots of your constraints from size inspector view. Make sure to cover them all.

Comment: I'm not sure where to post the screen shots as I can't include them in a comment. Should I answer my own question? That seems to be the only way I can include screenshots.

Comment: Have just posted the screenshots here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34285928/centering-two-side-by-side-objects

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do that is to embed both pickers in a horizontal [`UIStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/).

The stack view will equally space the two pickers, and they will appear horizontally centered as you asked.

The nice thing about stack views is that you don't need to constrain the pickers.  The stack view automatically manages laying out its children, and all you have to provide are constraints for the stack view itself in relation to its superview.