# Centering two side-by-side objects

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm trying to follow the solution described here:

[XCode 7 Autolayout Constraints: How to make 2 images stay horizontally in the center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544940/xcode-7-autolayout-constraints-how-to-make-2-images-stay-horizontally-in-the-ce/33545857#33545857)

But it is not working for me.

These are the screenshots from the Attribute Inspector for the constraints that I ended up with:

[image]

[image]

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: To make this easier to answer, it would be helpful if you edited your question to be specific about a) what you want, b) what you've tried, and c) what your current result looks like. Just linking to a different question and saying "I want that but it isn't working" makes your question harder for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You turned the constraints around - the leading/trailing of the image views have to be connected to the center of the superview to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: can you give me step-by-step instructions?

Comment: Your  first item is Superview.Trailing where it should be PickerView.Trailing (or Leading), and your second item is PickerView.Trailing where it should be Superview.CenterX.

Comment: How do I get it so that the first item is PickerView.Trailing? I am control clicking on the left pickerview and then dragging to the top right corner of the superview. Should I be doing something different?

Comment: Control-drag from the first view (pickerview) to the second (superview) should work - if not, try the other way around. Then select the constraint, click the second item dropdown box and select Center X.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever I do, I always get SuperView.Trailing in the first item. Maybe I have it set up wrong? This is what I have:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are the screenshots of what you require to achieve. I have kept image views' *content mode* to *aspect fit*. Let me know if you need more clarity.

1. Scene containing views (I've set superview's background color to *red*):
   [image: Scene containing views]
2. View hierarchy with constraints:
   [image: View hierarchy with constraints]

Answer (score 0):

I realise now what the issue was. I had put in all the correct constraints on the Storyboard but I had not added the necessary code to the View Controller. I was simply using the View Controller that is automatically generated by Xcode when you create a project (I had not even created IB outlets for the two picker views).

Now, when I add this code into the VC, the layout with the two side-by-side pickers displays fine:

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

```
var pickerDataSource = ["inch", "feet","mile","meter","yard","kilometer"];


@IBOutlet weak var picker1: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var picker2: UIPickerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    picker1.dataSource = self;
    picker1.delegate = self;

    picker2.dataSource = self;
    picker2.delegate = self;

}


func CreateColor(hexAlpha: Int, hexRed: Int, hexGreen: Int, hexBlue: Int) -> CGColor{
    return UIColor(red: CGFloat(hexRed)/255.0, green: CGFloat(hexGreen)/255.0, blue: CGFloat(hexBlue)/255.0, alpha: CGFloat(hexAlpha)/255.0).CGColor
}


func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerDataSource.count;
}



func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerDataSource[row]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Thanks for all your responses!